# Facebook Graph API - Fetching Address, but null

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, street-address

I have been trying to fetch my address by using the Graph API Explorer :

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ :

1. Get token
2. Enabled all the checks
3. Create token
4. Add fields 'address'
5. Set address in FB-profile
6. Search
7. API can't find any address?

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you will get the `address` only if the user has set it to public

Comment: you are definitely missing something: your code in the question.

Comment: @suzan the address is set to public, thank you. But still not working

Comment: you should add your piece of code so that we could understand what you are missing

Comment: Thank you guys, but I'm using the graph API explorer. So there's not really any code for this example. 

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/, log-in, add your token, search, add the field 'address' and voila @suzan

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure Facebook allows the extraction of that level of individual data anymore. They made major changes to the graph in late January, just before the Cambridge analytica controversy

The only way you probably could get that level of data is perhaps using something like Selenium or Scrapy.

Comment: Selenium and Scrapy will only work until you get banned. Facebook Terms of Service does not allow you to scrape them

Comment: I was assuming the same thing, but then still. The option 'address' is still available in the graph api... @Robert FC

Answer (score 1):

You need to give `user_location` permission while requesting for the token.

then

you can use

```
me?fields=id,name,location
```

to get the location of the user.

The response will be in the format

```
{
  "id": "userID",
  "name": "Profile name",
  "location": {
    "id": "randomID",
    "name": "name of the location"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I was actually hoping for a more "extended" address. Location is a step closer, but sadly it only refers to the city/country. (ex: shipping address)

Comment: i do not think you can get address in that much depth